# Pagination not working correctly in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pagination

I have a page that enables user to filter results using various filters. When I use a filter (for example writer), I get pagination as well. But when I click page 2, pagination works like there is no filter. How can I fix it? Thanks. Here's my view :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Reporting", "Book",FormMethod.Get))
{
    <p>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Publication Name : @Html.TextBox("nameSearch", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)
                    <input type="submit" value="Search in names" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style ="background-color:white">
                <td>
                    Writer : @Html.TextBox("writerSearch", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)
                    <input type="submit" value="Search in writers" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color:white">
                <td>
                    Publication No : @Html.TextBox("publicationNoSearch", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)
                    <input type="submit" value="Search in publication no" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color:white">
                <td>
                    Is On Sale : @Html.DropDownList("isOnSale", new List<SelectListItem>
                                     {
                                         new SelectListItem {Text = "", Value=null},
                                         new SelectListItem {Text = "Yes", Value="Yes"},
                                         new SelectListItem {Text = "No", Value="No"},

                                     }, ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)
                    <input type="submit" value="List" />
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>

    </p>
}

<table style="border : 1px solid black;">
    <tr style="border : 1px solid black;">
        <th style="border : 1px solid black;">
            Publication No
        </th>
        <th style="border : 1px solid black;">
        Writer
        </th>
        <th style="border : 1px solid black;">

            Publication Name

        </th>

    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{


    <tr style="border : 1px solid black;">
        <td style="border : 1px solid black;" width="100">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PublicationNo)
        </td>
        <td style="border : 1px solid black;" width="290">
            @if (item.Yazari != null)
            {
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Writer)
            }
        </td>

        <td style="border: 1px solid black; font-style: italic;" width="360">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PublicationName)
        </td>
</table>

<br/>

Page :  @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) / @Model.PageCount

<div class="yui3-cssreset">
    @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Reporting",
    new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
</div>
```

And this is my controller :

```
public ActionResult Reporting(string nameSearch, string writerSearch, string publicationNoSearch,string isOnSale , string CurrentFilter, int? page)
{

    if (nameSearch != null)
    {
        page = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        nameSearch = CurrentFilter;
    }

    ViewBag.CurrentFilter = nameSearch;

    var books = from b in db.Book select b;


    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(isimSearch))
    {
        books = books.Where(b => b.PublicationName.Contains(nameSearch));
    }
    else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(writerSearch))
    {
        books = books.Where(b => b.Writer.Contains(writerSearch));
    }
    else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(publicationNoSearch))
    {
        int publicationNoForSearch;
        publicationNoForSearch = Int32.Parse(publicationNoSearch);
        books = books.Where(b => b.PublicationNo == publicationNoForSearch);
    }
    else if (isOnSale == "Yes")
    {
        books = books.Where(b => b.isOnSale == true);
    }
    else if (isOnSale == "No")
    {
        books = books.Where(b => b.isOnSale == false);
    }
    else
    {
        ;
    }

    books = books.OrderBy(b => b.PublicationNo);
    int pageSize = 50;
    int pageNumber = (sayfa ?? 1);

    return View(books.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the values to your `Url.Action()` in the `Html.PagedListPager()` method. Currently you only add values for `sortOrder` and `currentFilter` (and `sortOrder` is not even a parameter in the `Reporting()` so that is a bit pointless).

In your method you need to set `ViewBag` properties for `writerSearch`, `publicationNoSearch` etc in the same way you are currently doing for `CurrentFilter`,and then modify the `Url.Action()` to add the values, for example

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Reporting",
    new { page, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter, writerSearch = ViewBag.WriterSearch, publicationNoSearch = ViewBag.PublicationNoSearch, etc })
```